# Pass By Reference C++, Vector of pointers. What is happening here?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, pass-by-reference

I dont think there is any question which points out to explanation I am looking for.

In this example (tryme() function in the ABC class), why does the parent's myfunction get executed when object is created and its reference is assigned directly passed as an argument to the function.

```
class parent
{
public:
      int abc;
      parent(){};
      ~parent(){};
      virtual void myfunction(void)
      {
          abc = 5;
          output("parent myfunction abc %d", abc);
      };
};

class child :public parent
{

public:
    int abc;
    child(int val):abc(val){};
    child(){};
    ~child(){};

    virtual void myfunction(void)
    {
        output("child myfunction abc %d", abc);
    }
};

class ABC
{
        std::vector<parent *> pvec;
        void test(parent* t)
        {
           pvec.pushback(t);
        }; 

        void tryme()
        {
             child c1 = child(3);
             child c2 = child(6);

             ABC::test(&c1); <-------- this executed child - I understand
             ABC::test(&c2); <-------- this executed child - I understand
             ABC::test(&child(9)); <-------- this executed parent - I dont understand
             ABC::test(&child(11));<-------- this executed parent - I dont understand

             for each (auto it in pvec)
             {
                   it->myfunction();
             }
        }
 }
```

output is

```
   child myfunction abc 3
   child myfunction abc 6
   parent myfunction abc 5
   parent myfunction abc 5
```

what is the different between 

`child c1 = child(3); 
&c1;`

and

`&child(3)`

Thanks

Comment: `test(&child(9));` will store a dangling pointer to a temporary `child` object that gets destroyed after `test` returns. So you are facing UB here.

Comment: c1 and c2 are not much better.

Comment: Are you sure it got executed ? I can see warning in xcode     ABC::test(&child(9));  //taking the object of a temporary object of type "child"

Comment: @HariomSingh Yes, it got executed. My code is slightly different, but I dont see any warning.

Comment: @manni66 , what do you mean by c1 and c2 are not much better. Thanks.

Comment: @VTT Thanks. Do you have any suggestion about how to implement it without having for user to create the object first and then pass the reference to the function. I want to make it as simple (or shorter version) to write as possible.

Comment: c1 and c2, like the other temporary objects, go out of scope at the end of `tryme()`, thus you have a dangling pointer to a nonexisent object

Comment: @ArnavBorborah, Oh Yes, thanks, Actually this is just an isolated code that I used here to explain my issue. But thanks, I got the whole idea about dangling pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things... Your title indicates you are "Passing by Reference".  You are in fact passing "By Pointer".

Also, When you call

```
ABC::test(&c1);
```

You are taking the address of your stack variable `c1` and passing it to your function.  Your array then stores the address of the object.  This is ok for the first two calls.

But... when you call

```
ABC::test(&child(9));
```

You are creating a temporary object which will only be valid for the duration of the function call and passing its address to the function, which then stores a "dangling" pointer to the temporary object.

When the function call is over, the object is destroyed.  By the array is still holding on the pointer to the now garbage memory.

The fact that it calls the "Parent" function call later on is just completely random, undefined behavior.  It just as easily could have printed out the meaning of life, or in the olden days, fried your monitor.  :)

Comment: Ha ha.. thanks, I am not sure I would have understood the meaning of life, but sure I understood the problem here. Thanks again.